# Spring Rest Template Post Both Data and Post Param

Tags: java, spring, post, resttemplate

How can I send post both data and post param with Spring Rest Template? I mean I want to do the same thing as follows within my Java app:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/uno/json?eso=tru -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
[
 {"id" : "TestDoc2", "hry" : "go"}
]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just build the URI

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder
    .fromHttpUrl("http://localhost:8080/uno/json")
    .queryParam("eso", "tru").build().toUri();
```

Create an [`HttpEntity`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html) containing the body content you want and use one of the [`RestTemplate#exchange(..)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#execute-java.net.URI-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback-org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor-) methods

```
template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, responseType);
```

Comment: How can I send data? Should I set header?

Comment: @kamaci Through the `HttpEntity`, you can set the body and the headers.

Comment: @kamaci What did you try and how/why didn't it work?

Comment: @kamaci Did you have any solution at last ? Seems like I am stuck in a very frustrating situation where I have tried literally everything but I am not able to send both request params and request body. I run in one or other error but fixing the solutions provided by community seems to be in vain for me. Can you or Sotirios please help me with something ?